# PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iphone 11pro ios 15.0 device. The video is playable but When I call 'deleteAssets' the 'completionHandler' never runs.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges {
    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(deleteAccess as NSFastEnumeration)
} completionHandler: { [weak self] success, error in 
    //Never run
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: How you resolve this issue? I am also facing issue.

Comment: I understand the problem belongs to ios, my solution is just to reset iphone.
In my code,  I show a message on app after a little delay and if user can't use it, I ask them to reset their iphone

Answer (score 0):

I do not know. But after I reset my iPhone, everything is back to normal. Maybe it's a system error.

Comment: My app many users facing same issue. Is there any solution for that?